# Unable to generate proper classes from xsd

Tags: java, xml, xsd, cxf

I am trying to generate Question and Tag classes from the Question.xsd. But I am not able to add 2(or more) tags to the Question. If I do `<xs:element ref="schemas:Tag">` it works (but will restrict to adding one tag). It also works if I remove `<xs:element name="Tag">` and place name in `<xs:complexType >` instead of Tag node.But the generated ArrayOfTag contains List of String instead of List of Tag. What is correct way of achieving this?

```
 <xs:element name="Question">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>

            **<xs:element  name ="tag1" type="schemas:Tag"/>
            <xs:element name ="tag2" type="schemas:Tag"/>**

        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>


<xs:element name="ArrayOfTag">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="schemas:Tag"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

    <xs:element name="Tag">
    <xs:complexType >
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="tagCode" type="xs:string" /> 
            <xs:element name="tagName" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would suffice your need. Instead of making Tag an element, make it complextype so that instead of using ref you can use type wherever you want an element of type tag.

```
<xs:element name="Question">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
          <xs:element name="tag1" type="Tag" />
          <xs:element name="tag2" type="Tag"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="ArrayOfTag">
   <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ArrayofTag" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="Tag"/>
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="Tag">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="tagCode" type="xs:string" /> 
        <xs:element name="tagName" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Yes, I was able to figure this out. Thanks for posting correct answer.